# Call to a member function links() on null in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make tags filter on my page, but I have an error says **Call to a member function links() on null**.

Thank you for anything you can do to help.

This is my controller:

```
<?php

public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('cari')) {
        $forums = \App\Forum::where('title','LIKE','%'.$request->cari.'%')->paginate(5);
    } elseif($request->has('tags')) {
        $tag = Tag::find($request->tags);
        $forums = $tag->forums;
    } else {
        $forums = Forum::paginate(5);
    }
    
    $populars = DB::table('forums')
        ->join('comments','forums.id','=','comments.commentable_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(commentable_id) as count'),'forums.id','forums.title','forums.slug')
        ->groupBy('id','title','slug')
        ->orderBy('count','desc')
        ->take(5)
        ->get();

    return view('forum.index', compact('forums','populars'));
}
```

And this is my link in view:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
     {!! $forums->links() !!}
</div>
```

This is my forum model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class forum extends Model
{

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

Comment: `$forums` is null. It's probably coming that way from your `if` or `else if`

Comment: Can you show off the code of `Forum::class` model?

Comment: Unless $request->tags is an id, Tag::find is not going to return your tags

Comment: @Kurt_Friars `Model::find()` accepts an array with IDs too.

Comment: i have try not to use if and else if, and its stilll have the sam error.

Comment: This is happen for else if

Comment: Well, where is the method `links()` as you're calling it on an object of `App\Forum::class`?